# How can I generate javadocs using Java?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm writing a Java app that will let me compile a Java project *based solely on it's file structure* so that I can write code and compile without an IDE. The problem that I'm currently having is that I would like to automatically generate the javadoc while I'm compiling, though while Java 6 supplies a JavaCompiler object to work with, I can't find a way to use the javadoc command.

How can I generate the javadoc html for my projects using Java code?

Comment: Why?  There are already mature Java build tools out there that do all of this and lots more.  Use one of them, and avoid creating a huge technological debt for yourself and/or the person who takes over your code.

Comment: I will no doubrt be told off for this, but:

Ant/Maven/Gradle all require a config file to be composed. If you have made a utility that doesn't need one, then there's a definite use case for this :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case you weren't aware both [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) and [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) are tools that exist to accomplish a similar goal to what you are writing (compiling without an IDE).

Both of them have built in support for generating javadoc.  Ant syntax looks like this:

```
<!-- publish javadoc -->
<target name="javadoc" description="Creates javadoc for IMP.">
      <delete dir="${web-javadoc}"/>
      <javadoc sourcepath="${source}"
               defaultexcludes="no"
               destdir="${web-javadoc}"
               author="true"
               version="true"
               use="true"
               windowtitle="IMP: Integrated Mechanisms Program"
               overview="${source}/overview.html"
               classpathref="debug.classpath"
               stylesheetfile="${javadoc-theme}/stylesheet.css"
       />

       <copy file="${javadoc-theme}/javadoc.jpg" tofile="${web-javadoc}/javadoc.jpg"/>
</target>
```

If you really want to generate it on your own you want to use the [Doclet API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html)

```
import com.sun.javadoc.*;

public class ListClass {
    public static boolean start(RootDoc root) {
        ClassDoc[] classes = root.classes();
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; ++i) {
            System.out.println(classes[i]);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very thorough. I appreciate you giving me the answer to my question even if you thought it was dumb.

Comment: Just wanted to save you some time if those tools met your needs. Didn't think it was dumb.

Answer (score 5):

> The Javadoc tool has a programmatic interface with public methods for invoking the Javadoc tool from another program written in the Java language. These methods are located in class `com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main` in `lib/tools.jar`.

From: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically

Answer (score 5):

In a terminal, type `javadoc` - it will give you a nice list of options. Simplest:

```
javadoc -d your_output_directory -classpath your_classpath -sourcepath your_sourcefile_dir
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Running the Standard Doclet Programmatically](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically) in the tool docs.

Comment: There is no real problem with your answer, just the answer from miku is a bit better (and came some minutes earlier), and I wanted to make sure it is ranked a before your answer. Sorry, the downvote was the only way to make this happen.

Comment: @Paŭlo: I see. By my understanding, that's not a good use of downvoting. Downvotes are for marking out harmful or incorrect answers.

Comment: This is a limit case, yes. Sorry it hit you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a javadoc command, it comes with the JDK(man javadoc on unix platforms)

However, there are better ways.  How are you compiling code?  If you are using an automated build tool such as ant or maven, you can add a javadoc task to automatically generate the javadocs whenever you compile your code

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javadoc.html

for more info on ant(other tools have similar functionality, refer to your tools documentation for more info)

That is what I do, it works brilliantly.